# How to disable automatic import statements in VsCode October 2017

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

The latest version of VS Code installed a few days ago (the October 2017 update) keeps adding all kinds of strange import statements to the top of the .ts code file.

For example, as I was editing a file, VsCode suddenly added a line like this to the top of the file:

```
import { Stack } from "../../../../../../../../../Repos/Web/node_modules/@types/d3";
```

How do I disable this behavior?

Comment: Same. In ES6 files, the IDE seems to think i'm doing NodeJS dev and tries to import all kinds of nodejs defaults.

Comment: I love the editor but this feature is annoying. It never gets the path right and usually just means you waste time trying to figure out why your app has crashed after changing one line. Glad you can turn it off but that should not be a default!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
"typescript.suggest.autoImports": false 
"javascript.suggest.autoImports": false
```

Fresh VS Code version. February 2019

Answer (score 44):

You can disable it by adding this line to your user or workspace settings (`File>Preferences>Settings`, or `Code>Preferences>Settings`).

```
"typescript.autoImportSuggestions.enabled": false
```

Ref.: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/38551

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. But I must say the description of this flag in the official VsCode release docs (https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_18#_auto-import-for-javascript-and-typescript) is misleading, and that is why I had to come here to ask the question. The release docs make it sound as if this flags only controls the import suggestions that pop up when typing code, whereas it applies as well to the automatic imports added by VsCode.

Comment: The suggestions and the actual auto-imports are one and the same. Disable autoimports and you no longer get suggestions for exported members from other files

Comment: Where does this setting go?

Comment: It goes in your user settings or workspace settings file. You can access it this way: `File>Preferences>Settings`.

Comment: I can confirm as of 1.25, it doesn't always work. Don't know when, how, why it happens, but pretty annoying to say the very least.

Comment: For me, it also doesn't always work... Even though this definition is set to false, many times the editor imports the componenet/module automatically and sometimes even does it wrongly...

Comment: Could you have a folder or workspace specific config overriding this one?

Comment: The Vscode version I run on mac (`1.37.0`) has settings under `Code` instead of `File`:  `Code>Preferences>Settings`

Comment: Is this the correct setting for `typescript` and [the most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54614569/1705829) for both?

Answer (score 21):

Updated for new version of **VSCode 2019** for using the UI to modify the setting. 
So choose the ***File > Preference > Setting*** then search `auto` in the Workspace secton. Find the Javascrtip or Typescript with highlight word `auto import` then check or uncheck for enable / disalbe this function.

Here is the picture for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As of August 2018 (1.25), the accepted answer doesn't always work.

Instead, add this line to your folder-specific setting.

```js
{  "typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative" }
```

Don't figure what's going on here, but those automatic path changes never happen in my environment.

Answer (score 1):

For those using React/JavaScript you have to edit this setting in File > Preferences > Settings:

```
"javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "never",
```

Comment: This isn't what OP was asking for - this is when files are moved and is a separate behavior than when VScode tries to figure out (usually wrongly) what you want to import.