# How to disable automatic ES6 import statements in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

[Reference to a similar question for VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47350589/1090571)

Since one of the more recent updates, VS2017 has been adding automatic imports when autocompleting statements in JS with tab/enter. This has lead to some frustrating incidents where it tries to import some faraway module when using things like `setTimeout` or `document`.

In VS Code, as seen in the referenced question, it is possible to turn this off. I have not been able to locate a similar setting in VS2017. Is it possible to disable or configure this behaviour?

Furthermore, it has also started inserting snippets (for example, with `class`). Is it possible to disable/configure this setting as well?

I am currently using version 15.6.7.

Comment: did you find an answer? The reference to similar question is not helpful at all

Comment: I *think* you are unhappy about the auto-discovery feature of the Salsa language service.  You can configure it with a tsconfig.json file, enableAutoDiscovery setting.  Details [are here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-New-Language-Service-in-Visual-Studio-15-Preview).

Comment: Thanks to @HansPassant I was able to find the solution. Apparently, without a `tsconfig.json` file, the autocomplete list will list two entries for `setTimeout`. One is a reference to the native JS implementation, the other to `NodeJS.Timers`. When I place a `tsconfig.json` file in the root of my project (regardless of content - it can even be empty!), Visual Studio will stop suggesting the `NodeJS.Timers` variant, and I can safely use tab-autocomplete without importing unnecessary files. I am not sure why this is happening, or what other consequences it has, but for me this is a solution.

Comment: My previously mentioned 'workaround' also requires at least one `.ts` file, otherwise `MSBuild` will fail with an error.

Comment: @IvoCoumans Kindly post an answer accordingly. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a workaround, you can create an (empty) `tsconfig.json` file in the root of your project. This will stop Visual Studio from trying to import `NodeJS` libraries, which was the cause of my problem.

Note that if you are using `MSBuild` to build your project (e.g. through TFS), you will also need to add at least one `.ts` file to your project. This can also be empty. For example, I added an empty `empty.ts` file to the root of my project.

It's not beautiful, but it works for now.