# Your test suite must contain at least one test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have updated some of the dependencies today in my project, but it went through really smoothly. Now, when I'm about to push it, I started my tests. And boom. All of them throw:

`Your test suite must contain at least one test.`

My packages:

```
"jest": "23.1.0",
"jest-enzyme": "^6.0.1",
"jest-webpack-alias": "^3.3.3",
"jsdom": "^11.2.0",
"jsdom-global": "^3.0.2",
"enzyme": "3.3.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.0",
"enzyme-to-json": "3.3.4",
```

And that is how my sample test file looks like:

**/shared/components/App/MyRoute/__tests__/MyRoute.test.js**

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { ContactsRoute } from '../Route';

describe('<ContactsRoute />', () => {
  test('renders', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ContactsRoute t={key => key} />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

I have no idea why they stopped running so suddenly?

**Edit - adding my jest config**

```
  "jest": {
"collectCoverageFrom": [
  "shared/**/*.{js,jsx}"
],
"globals": {
  "JWT_SECRET": "local",
  "IS_TEST": "true"
},
"snapshotSerializers": [
  "<rootDir>/node_modules/enzyme-to-json/serializer"
],
"testPathIgnorePatterns": [
  "<rootDir>/(build|internal|node_modules|flow-typed|public|shared/services)/"
],
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/_test_config_/mocks/fileMock.js"
},
"testURL": "http://localhost:3005",
"transform": {
  ".": "<rootDir>/_test_config_/preprocessors/webpackAlias.js",
  "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/_test_config_/preprocessors/cssTransform.js",
  "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/_test_config_/preprocessors/fileTransform.js"
},
"setupFiles": [
  "<rootDir>/_test_config_/preprocessors/polyfills.js"
],
"setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./node_modules/jest-enzyme/lib/index.js"
},
```

Comment: `test()` isn't a thing.  `it()` is.

Comment: @DanO was this changed in some recent versions?

Comment: Using the same version of `Jest`. `test()` works fine for me.

Comment: @DanO Jest has test() which is equivalent to it().

Comment: huh, I'd never heard of it and I didn't see it in a (quick, non-exhaustive) search of the docs.  learn something new every day, I guess.

Comment: you may want to disable the 'Your test suite must contain at least one test' rule in Jest [Disabling the 'Your test suite must contain at least one test' rule in Jest](//stackoverflow.com/q/54477404)

Answer (score 59):

#### make sure describe / it/ expect variables are not been imported

In my case, the IDE( VSCode ) automatically import the variable `describe` from another library.

Comment: How did you fix that?

Comment: @xtra you mean the auto import? I just delete the automatically added import sentence manually and disabled the VSCode auto-import function. [here's an ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350589/how-to-disable-automatic-import-statements-in-vscode-october-2017)

Comment: If this happens, next step is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57874114/intellisense-for-jest-not-working-in-vs-code to have VSCode understand the jest globals.

Comment: @J.G.Sebring nice add to the solution

Comment: This was my issue. vscode imported describe/it/test from `node:test` instead of `@jest/globals`

Comment: Vscode imported "test" from node test and that wasted my 2 hours

Answer (score 23):

Make sure that you have at least one `describe / it / expect`

In my case, i wrote just a `describe / expect` test and got this error message

Comment: jest/test/expect gives this error too. Replacing "test" with "it" fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 21):

If all the other responses fail, if you have any files named `test.js`, Jest will expect that file to contain a test.

I was using a file named test.js to manually test some stuff, and Jest was throwing this error. I re-named the file to something else (eg: 123.js) and I stopped getting this error message.

Comment: Damnn thanks this was the issue in my case

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Not sure why Jest does this, and the logs aren't helpful at all either.

Comment: Another option besides renaming the file is to configure `testMatch` to be more specific. I set it to `**/?*.test.ts`

Comment: my js method was called `test` and that ruined it

Comment: Exactly, may be you have a .test file with no test in it.

Answer (score 9):

May be you forgot it() block:

maybe you have a mistake and in somewhere code is like this:

```
describe('some text', () => {
    expect(...)...;
});
```

replace it with:

```
describe('some text', () => {
    it('my test', () => {
        expect(...)...;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. The below steps solved the issue for me.
**Step 1:**

```
rm -rf ./dist
```

**Step 2:** Edit `tsconfig.json`

```
{ 
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/*.test.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A common source of this error is that Jest picks up some file, expecting it to contain tests, when in fact it's just some random file that the developer never intended for Jest to act on.

Here is how Jest identifies test files by default ([source](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration)):

> By default it looks for .js, .jsx, .ts and .tsx files inside of __tests__ folders, as well as any files with a suffix of .test or .spec (e.g. Component.test.js or Component.spec.js). It will also find files called test.js or spec.js.

Here are some hypothetical examples of files that would inadvertently be picked up by Jest:

- `__tests__/mocks.js` - a file containing some mock data for other tests.
- `util.test.js` - a file containing utility functions for other tests.
- `test.js` - a file that exports some dummy component for ad hoc manual testing.

You can solve this problem in one of two ways:

1. Rename the file so that Jest does not find it.
2. Configure Jest to ignore the file using [`testMatch`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring) or [`testRegex`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testregex-string--arraystring).

Note: Several existing answers reference specific instances of this problem (e.g. `test.js` or `__tests__/*.js`). This answer is intended to be more general and comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For this one "a file containing utility functions for other tests", if I name it "util.js" then jest won't find it, but how do I prevent Webpack to bundle it? Do I need to use IgnorePlugin or I can just rely on Tree shaking (as App codes won't import it)?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your `describe` function is not async

```js
// Wrong
describe('setPackages', async () => {
 // ...
});

// Correct
describe('setPackages', () => {
 // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to call Jest with the `--passWithNoTests` argument, as documented [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--passwithnotests).
The flag is useful when you don't know how many tests a script will run, such as with git commit hooks.

Answer (score 1):

another issue which raises this Error is when you have put some none-test files into your `__test__` directory.

**All** files in your `__test__` directory must include some tests to run.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the answer.

The `Note` in [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#transform-object-string-string) says that if we are using `babel-jest` alongside with our own preprocessors, the `babel-jest` has to be explicitly defined in the `transform` option.

It is important to add `"^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"` as the first option in the `transform` config.

Answer (score 0):

Might happen when you have a test file but the contents are not saved? Try saving the file before running the tests.

Answer (score 0):

For my typescript users out there with this issue. Use `yarn tsc -watch` or `npm tsc -watch`. I just forgot to build my ts files to js and hence the case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a wrongly closed curly braces of beforeEach function,

Because of wrong location of this curly braces my it() function seemed like it was inside the beforeEach function. Therefore jest wasn't able to ident

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I removed the following entry from my test file for example : `my_module.test.ts`.

```
import test from "node:test";
```

After that (**describe|test|expect**) and (**describe| it|expect**) both worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was because I had mock data in my `__tests__` folder.
The way I solved it is to tell jest to ignore those files by using the property `modulePathIgnorePatterns` in `jest.config.ts`.
you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40486567/how-can-i-exclude-files-from-jest-watch) question to set it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a platform file called test.ts it was picking up. Within jest.config.ts I added:

```
testMatch: ['**/tests/**/*.[jt]s?(x)', '**/?(*.)+(spec).[jt]s?(x)'],
```

This overrode the default:

```
(default: [ "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)", "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)" ])
```

Docs here:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring