# Jest doesn't see tests described with test() function, but works ok with it()

Tags: testing, jestjs

When describing tests using:

`it('foo', () => {...})`

all tests pass.

But when I change the test to

`test('foo', () => {...})`

Jest fails with "Your test suite must contain at least one test."

Found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50843511/your-test-suite-must-contain-at-least-one-test), but nothing worked.

Using latest Jest, have the following presets in `babel.config.js`:

```
 'presets': [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-react'
 ],
```

Comment: Debug what `it` and `test` are in your case. They should be the same. In case you redefined `test` somewhere, this obviously won't work.

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks, indeed there was a global variable from the app code.