# VSCode appears to automatically be adding an import to the top of scripts

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code

I am working on a Python project in VSCode with multiple files containing functions, being called from other files, like I have many other times.
However, I noticed that, sometimes, the following line appears at the top of some files:

```
    from asyncore import read
```

I removed it, and now once I checked the file after altering others, it's back! It is making me go mad. It even is in the git push I did, although I am sure I removed it before sending it. Does anyone know what this is? Thank you.

Comment: Some python extension you are using is doing this. It happens to me too sometimes, but usually only if I call a function that I have not imported yet. A lot of times it's guessing the right import. Occasionally it gets it wrong.

Comment: @TheFool Could it maybe be Pylance, or something built in VSCode itself? I have seen other weird imports in the code, now that I am having a look.. The imports are completely wrong! But thank you, I will have a look at what extensions I have, I was scared of some malicious backdoor already haha

Comment: I am guessing its pylance.

Comment: I was having the same issue, but had never enabled it myself.  Found out it was enabled by `ms-python.black-formatter` in `User settings.json`.  Check there even if you're sure you never turned it on.

Answer (score 10):

You can disable it by adding this line to your user or workspace settings (File>Preferences>Settings, or Code>Preferences>Settings).

```
"python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": false
```

This Pylance extension setting is documented [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance).  Turning off this setting is similar to this [SO:answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47350638) except for Python instead of typescript.