# VS Code randomly imports libraries in my Python Scripts

Tags: python, visual-studio

I feel like I am going crazy. Random libraries have started to become imported into my python scripts while working in visual studio code.

The other day, I pulled up some old code and noticed a very strange library import at the top.

```
from turtle import right
```

This had nothing to do with my program and I thought someone was pranking me - which would be quite odd to do this in this file I have not opened in months and the library import had no meaning to me.

A couple of weeks later, I start working on a different python script and within the same day, while at home, no one with me, another random library import occurs in my script.

```
from telnet import DO
```

Can someone please give me a reason why this could be happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode appears to automatically be adding an import to the top of scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70777612/vscode-appears-to-automatically-be-adding-an-import-to-the-top-of-scripts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VSCode has an auto import feature. If you press enter while it suggests you some method/object, it will be automatically added as an import if it is not in the namespace already.

[image]

Comment: what a very fine feature!

Comment: this bloody thing imported 'this'...and had me scratching my head as to why flask was preaching Zen of Python to me...

Answer (score 0):

Python auto-imports libraries from their keywords by default. You can disable this in the settings.

Comment: VSCode auto imports. Python does not.