# How to stop Visual Studio 2022 to add namespace automatically after copy codes from other place

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

As the title said, now I have a problem when copy codes from anywhere, and when pasting to my source files (C#/.cs), it will add a namespace automatically, sometimes the namespace is wrong but I don't know because it was added as unused namespace, but it will have a problem later when I build the project (with Unity) because it can't find the namespace, Then I have to delete it, it is very annoying.

Comment: There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71607251) for VSCode and Python.  A similar approach may help with Visual Studio and C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is referring to the setting Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Add missing using directives on paste.

[image: Showing the checkbox for Add missing using directives on paste]

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the 'Enable namespace update when moving files' option.

In Visual Studio 2022 access the setting via the menu by following...

Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General