# Prevent certain files from being imported in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

In TypeScript, how can I prevent certain files from being imported?

More specifically, VS Code will autosuggest import statements as you're typing. In my scenario, many of the files are generated and will never need to be imported. So as you're typing, VS Code will suggest all these extra files, making it difficult to find the actual source code files.

[image]

There are many ways (e.g., linting) to throw errors if certain files are ever imported, but I'm mainly interested in preventing the import suggestions. [Typescript prevent imports from certain directory in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52579681/typescript-prevent-imports-from-certain-directory-in-project)

Lastly, I know it's possible to disable import suggestions alltogether, but I'd still like to keep that functionality. [How to disable automatic import statements in VsCode October 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350589/how-to-disable-automatic-import-statements-in-vscode-october-2017)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now disable certain files from auto importing using [`typescript.preferences.autoImportFileExcludePatterns`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8-rc/#exclude-specific-files-from-auto-imports). This requires TypeScript `4.8` or greater.

In your `settings.json`:

```json
{
  "typescript.preferences.autoImportFileExcludePatterns": [
    "./path/to/file/**/my-file.ts",
  ]
}
```

Comment: What about stuff in node_modules? I've tried variations of `./node_modules/@blueprintjs/**/*` etc but nothing works. If I try typing `Overlay` it shows everything from blueprint.