# How to selecting between different import paths in VS-CODE?

Tags: visual-studio-code, import, settings

This is documentation from [WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com):

## Selecting between different import paths

Sometimes the code is structured in such a way that there’s more than one way to import something. For example, to import a component in the Material-UI library you can use:

1

```js
import { AppBar, Button } from "@mui/material";
```

or

2

```js
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Button  from "@mui/material/Button";
```

The option “Do not import exactly from” allows you to tell the IDE that you don’t want any imports that are from the specific path (e.g. @material-ui/core) or path pattern (e.g. @material-ui/core/**). The IDE will then use an alternative path if there is one.

**I want to set the second option in vs-code (typescript project)**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent certain files from being imported in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71491519/prevent-certain-files-from-being-imported-in-vs-code) TL;DR you can't prevent the import suggestions entirely I think, but you can at least prevent things from being _auto_-imported.

Comment: [1] "Does this answer your question?" -> nope
[2] "you can't prevent the import suggestions entirely" -> I don't think so, I remember I had an import similar to (option 2) in one project, but I can't find it.